# React Combobox SPFx map out only unique values instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

As the title states I am trying to map out only unique values instead of the same repeating values.
My code where I map my data through can be seen below:

```
<ComboBox label='City' options={rooms.map((roomInfo): IComboBoxOption => {
return { key: roomInfo.id, text: roomInfo.location }})}/>
```

The data the combobox shows with following code above is something like:

```
location: New York
location: New York
location: Chicago
location: California
location: Chicago
```

What I want is:

```
location: New York
location: California
location: Chicago
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well you have **duplicate values** inside `rooms array`, you can remove duplicates:

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, location: 'New York' },
  { id: 2, location: 'New York' },
  { id: 3, location: 'Chicago' },
  { id: 4, location: 'California' },
]

const noDuplicates = data.filter((roomInfo, i, arr) => arr.findIndex(x => x.location === roomInfo.location) === i)
```